# AttributeError: module 'fractions' has no attribute 'Fraction'

Tags: python, python-module, atom-editor

I wanted to start studying of fractions module in Python. I use Atom editor and package "Script" for running a module from editor. So, I got this error trying to make simple fraction object:

> AttributeError: module 'fractions' has no attribute 'Fraction'

Code:

```
import fractions
f = fractions.Fraction(3, 4) + 1 + 1.5
print(f)
```

What's going wrong? Python intrepreter works with it without any problem.

Comment: What does `import fractions; print(fractions)` produce? You probably have a local `fractions.py` script somewhere that masks the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a local `fractions.py` script that masks the library. Python will look in your current directory for imports before the standard library, so make sure you don't give your scripts the same name as a library you want to use!

You can find out where that file lives by printing the imported module:

```
import fractions
print(fractions)
```

Rename or delete that file.